# undefined reference to class::function when I try to compile

Tags: c++

I have three files: Main.cpp, Security.h, and Security.cpp.

- I have declared my class Security (including a function) in my header file.
- I have defined the function in Security.cpp.
- My header file has been included in both Main.cpp and Security.cpp.
- In Main.cpp, I'm creating an object, and attempting to run the member function and keep getting a compile error.

Main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Security.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  Security S1;
  S1.Driver();
}
```

Security.h

```
class Security
{private:

 public:
 void Driver();
};
```

Security.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include "Security.h"
using namespace std;

void Securtiy::Driver()
{
  cout << "Enter a number: ";
  int answer;
  cin >> answer;

  cout << answer;
}
```

Comment: You are compiling *both* main.cpp *and* Security.cpp and linking them, right?

Comment: I'm only compiling Main.cpp using g++ in putty.  I know that trying to compile Security.cpp will give me an error because it lacks a main function.

Comment: Dave, it took me a second to realize what you were saying.  I needed to include Security.cpp in my Main.cpp file.  Now it compiles without an issue.

Comment: @KevinSimpsonII That isn't what Dave as saying, and that isn't what you should be doing. See Inspired's answer, that matches what I'm pretty sure Dave was trying to tell you.

Comment: @hvd - although it worked when I included it, I want to be sure I do things correctly.  So I followed Inspired's post.  The program is compiling and executing.

Comment: Yup that's what I was going for. @KevinSimpsonII only the *final, linked* file needs a `main` function. The point of linking is that each `cpp` file provides some functions, then you link them all together in the final product. As you noticed, `include` will also do the job, but as your project gets bigger you'll realise that doing it that way can make compilation very slow.

Answer (score 2):

`Securtiy` is a misspelling in your Security.cpp file.

Comment: I noticed that once I linked Security.cpp to Main.cpp and compiled.

Answer (score 2):

You should compile both files, because the definition of Security::Driver is in Security.cpp.

The easiest way would be to invoke a single command:

`g++ Main.cpp Security.cpp`

However, if you want to compile the files separately, you must compile them into an intermediate ('object') format using `-c` flag:

```
g++ -c Main.cpp
g++ -c Security.cpp
```

This will give you two object files. Now link them:

```
g++ Main.o Security.o
```